# Need help understanding parts of this class

Tags: java

I need someone to elaborate on certain parts of this code.

```
class ContinueWithLabelDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String searchMe = "Look for a substring in me";
    String substring = "sub";
    boolean foundIt = false;

    int max = searchMe.length() - 
              substring.length();

test:
    for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
        int n = substring.length();
        int j = i;
        int k = 0;
        while (n-- != 0) {
            if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++)) {
                continue test;
            }
        }
        foundIt = true;
            break test;
    }
    System.out.println(foundIt ? "Found it" : "Didn't find it");
}
}
```

more specifically, I don't understand this part:

```
int n = substring.length();
        int j = i;
        int k = 0;
        while (n-- != 0) {
            if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++)) {
                continue test;
            }
        }
```

Why is it necessary to declare j and k in this code at all? I know that there is a reason in it for the if statement

```
if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++))
```

but I don't understand what the code is actually doing at this part.

Also, what does

```
while (n-- != 0)
```

mean?

Comment: I believe you know what does -- and ++ do in Java. But you don't understand what does this `while` loop do exactly. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
while (n-- != 0)
```

This is just looping around, reducing n by 1 each time around the loop and ending when n (before) reducing it by 1 is not 0.

```
int n = substring.length();
int j = i;
int k = 0;
while (n-- != 0) {
    if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++)) {
        continue test;
    }
}
```

This code is starting with j and k at different positions in the string, and then it is looping through comparing the character in the String at that position. j++ just says "use the current value of j, and then afterwards add 1 to it".

Answer (score 0):

Starting with an `n >= 0` (string length can not be negative):

```
while (n-- != 0) {
    ... 
}
```

is just a substitute for

```
for (int t = n ; t > 0; t--) {
    .... // use t instead of n, no change in your example
}
```

it iterates just `n` times (length of substring).

Answer (score 0):

`++` and `--` are pre or post incrementor and decrementor in java.

Imagine the following code to understand the behaviour:

```
int a = 42
System.out.println(a++) // prints 42
System.out.println(a) // prints 43
System.out.println(++a) // prints 44
System.out.println(a) // prints 44
```

In fact, it adds or subtracts 1 before or after the statement is processed.

So in your situations, `while (n-- != 0)` means, that the condition is checked, wether `n` is not zero and after that decremented by 1.

To achieve the same, you could also write:

```
while (n != 0) {
    if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++)) {
        continue test;
    }
    n = n - 1 // or n-- or n -= 1
}
```

Your second condition `if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++))` compares the character at the index `j` in `searchMe` against the character with the index `k` from `substring` and after that increments both indices to avoid two more lines, where these two are incremented.

Answer (score 0):

This can be broken down in to the following:

```
outer: loop(/* for each character in searchMe to max */) {

    loop(/* for each character in substring
          * starting with current index in outer loop */) {

        if(/* this substring does not match */)
           continue /* with next outer loop iteration */;
    }

    /* if inner loop completed
     * the substring did match at this index so break */;
 }
```

Out of all the variables, `n` is actually the one that's not needed. I don't know why it's there except to try to confound. The while loop could just as easily read `while(k < substring.length())`.

This kind of loop is necessary because to search for a substring you have to search starting at every character:

```
Loo
ook
ok 
k f
 fo
for
or 
r a
...
a s
 su
sub <- found it
```

Another way to express the same logic is the following but this creates a new object on each iteration:

```
int max = searchMe.length() - substring.length();

for(int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    String toTest = searchMe.substring(i, i + substring.length());

    if(toTest.equals(substring)) {
        foundIt = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is some interesting code.  To start off, the label on your `break` is unnecessary.

Next, to your main questions:

- `n--` is a postfix decrement operator - the current value of `n` is evaluated, then it is decremented by 1. When `n` is evaluated next, it will have the value of `n-1`.

  In the context of the code `while(n-- != 0)` implies that, when `n == 1`, this loop will still execute, but the next time we see `n`, we will be viewing `0` instead.
- The statement:

  ```
  if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++)) {
      continue test;
  }
  ```

  ...indicates that, if the value in the position of the main search string doesn't match up with the value we're looking for, we need to immediately jump to the label `test`.  This allows you to skip the execution of the following two statements after it, and continue looping and looking for positive matches.

  `j` is constantly set to what `i` is, but it is not *always* equal to `i`.  If a partial positive match is found, then `j` will increment faster than `i` by virtue of the `while` loop around that statement.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class ContinueWithLabelDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String searchMe = "Look for a substring in me";
    String substring = "sub";
    boolean foundIt = false;

    int max = searchMe.length() - 
              substring.length(); //the length of what we're going to search through, we 
                                  //subtract the substring.Length because if the 3rd to 
                                  //last character of searchMe is not equal to the first 
                                  //character of substring then searchMe can not contain substring. 

test:
    for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {  //repeat until we pass the 3rd to last character of searchMe
        int n = substring.length(); //resets n to the length of the substring 
        int j = i; //resets j to equal i so we search for the next letter in searchMe
        int k = 0; //resets k to equal 0 so we search for the first letter in substring
        while (n-- != 0) { //repeat this loop until n = 0, each pass will subtract 1 from
//n.  this will loop a maximum of 3 times (the number of characters in substring)
            if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++)) { 
//the if statement above will add 1 to j and add 1 to k after it checks to make sure the 
//characters are not equal to each other.  if they are equal then it will take the new
//j and k variables and repeat the while loop.  
                continue test;  //if statement true then loop through the 'test' again.
            }
        }
        foundIt = true;
            break test;
    }
    System.out.println(foundIt ? "Found it" : "Didn't find it");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't know how to write simple things in a [tutorial for beginners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

This part:

```
int n = substring.length();
int j = i;
int k = 0;
while (n-- != 0) {
    if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++)) {
        continue test;
    }
}
```

can be changed to:

```
int n = substring.length();
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    if (searchMe.charAt(i + k) != substring.charAt(k)) {
        continue test;
    }
}
```

So, you don't need `j` and instead of that tricky `while` you can use a simple `for` which is more intuitive, because it iterates through the `substring`.